# How to handle Debug/TestFlight/AppStore releases without targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I use Cocoapods for my project and I need a specific set of frameworks for each Debug/TestFlight/AppStore release:

- **Debug (simulator or device):** common frameworks + Calabash - Google Analytics
- **TestFlight:** common frameworks + TestFlight SDK
- **App Store:** common frameworks only

I could use targets, but they are annoying:

- Every time you add a new file (or create one) you have to remember to add it to all targets. It makes it really easy to produce builds that don't have a required file.
- Changes in build settings of one target don't propagate to other targets (i.e: changing a llvm flag).

On the other hand, cocoapods doesn't support weak frameworks, so I can't weak-link to Calabash in my main target and force-load it when building in Debug mode (because it'll still be in the framework set when building for the app store)

What would be a good balance between the very segregated option that are targets, and "all in" solution of a single target?

Answer (score 0):

I have a [makefile](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2014/08/08/CocoaPods-Caching/) that removes certain pods then runs Pod install. We're making it much easier in the next release to do *config* based pods, so you will be able to do all of what your asking in version 0.34+. This is in the [current HEAD](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1791) on github.